# JPA not saving to DB on WildFly 16

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, persistence, jpa-2.1, wildfly-16

After migrating from Wildfly-8.2.0 to Wildfly-16.0.0, my JEE application launched normally and

displayed expected data read from (PostgreSql) database, but neither of the (insert/update/delete)

operations is saving to database (with no exception fired) !

I redeployed the same application on the old version of Wildfly and (insert/update/delete) operations worked.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me the packege where the `@Transactional` annotations are being imported? Can you also post an example of one of your "save" methods? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was missing is to add the "eclipselink.jar" file in

"wildfly\modules\system\layers\base\org\eclipse\persistence\main"

and reference it as a "resource-root" in

"wildfly\modules\system\layers\base\org\eclipse\persistence\main\module.xml"

Unfortunatelly, no exception was fired describing the missing configuration of eclipselink!